# Why does $\log_{10}(10^x + 1) - x$ approximate $\log_{10} e$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, numerical-methods, logarithms

I was calculating base-$10$ logarithms and noticed that $\log_{10}(10^k+1) - k$ approaches $\log_{10} e$.

In the screenshot below, `Log[a,b]` calculates $\log_ab$, and `N[p,q]` gives the numerical value of $p$ to $q$ digits.

[image]

---

**Question 1:** Why does $\log_{10}(10^x + 1)- x$ approximate $\log_{10} e$?

**Question 2:** Why $10^k+1$? I can't recognize the pattern when I try to calculate, e.g. $\log_{10}(10^k+2)$.

Comment: What does " log(10, 1000....001)" mean? 10, 1000....and then 001??

Comment: Your post is not clear.  For large $x$ we clearly have $\log_{10}(10^x+1)\approx x$.

Comment: Your work appears to show that $(\log_{10} (10^N+1)-N)10^N \approx \log_{10} e.$  Is that indeed what you are trying to show?

Comment: What do you mean log of something "to" base something?

Comment: I mean that log(2, x) = ln(2) / ln(x) = log of x to base 2

Comment: @Serge: I have edited your question to use standard mathematical notation and to be a bit more clear. Please double-check that the changes still match your  intention.

Comment: @Serge Note $\log(2,x) = \ln(x) / \ln(2)$ (you've written the reciprocal).  But I think the problem is specifically with the word "to" and not the math.  I have heard $\log_2(x)$ read "log base 2 of x" or maybe "log of x with base 2".  Saying "to" is common for exponents ( indices for some countries) but sounds awkward for bases.

Comment: @BrianMoehring, thank you for explanation. the reason why I wrote like this, was Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm?wprov=sfla1 — The logarithm of x to base b is denoted as log_b (x)

Comment: @Blue yrs, they match, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$e = \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n$$

Replace $n$ with $10^x$, apply $\log_{10}$ to both sides, use continuity of logarithms, and then simplify using basic properties of logs.

As for your second question, putting a $2$ in the one's digit would then use 
$$e^2 = \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac2n\right)^n$$
and then when you take logs, you get $\log_{10}(e^2)=2\log_{10}(e)$

Answer (score 0):

As per the picture, you compute
$$
\log_{10}(1+10^x)-x=\log_{10}(1+10^{-x})=\log_{10}e\cdot\ln(1+10^{-x})
$$
and $\ln(1+10^{-x})=10^{-x}-\frac1210^{-2x}+\frac1310^{-3x}+...$, which is exactly what you observe.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\log_{10}(x)=\frac{\log(x)}{\log(10)}$ and $\log(1+x)=x+O\!\left(x^2\right)$,
$$
\begin{align}
\log_{10}\left(10^n+k\right)-n
&=\log_{10}\left(1+k\,10^{-n}\right)\\[3pt]
&=\frac{\log\left(1+k\,10^{-n}\right)}{\log(10)}\\
&=\frac{k\,10^{-n}+O\!\left(10^{-2n}\right)}{\log(10)}\\[6pt]
&=k\log_{10}(e)\,10^{-n}+O\!\left(10^{-2n}\right)
\end{align}
$$

For example
$$
\begin{align}
\log_{10}\left(10^{\color{#C00}{50}}+\color{#090}{3}\right)-\color{#C00}{50}&=1.3028834457098\times10^{-\color{#C00}{50}}\\
\color{#090}{3}\,\log_{10}(e)&=1.3028834457098
\end{align}
$$